# Laravel required_if does not accept other parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have some problems with Laravel's validation. I'm using required_if validator.

*What I want to achieve:* When the **hilightColorBool** is **true** the hilightColor should be *required*, should be *integer* between *min:1* and *max:5*.

```
...
'hilightColorBool' => 'required|boolean',
'hilightColor' => 'required_if:hilightColorBool,1|integer|min:1|max:5'
...
```

But when I'm doing it like above it always returns that hilghtColor is bool, when I do remove the integer, min and max from hilightColor it works good, but I need to validate anyway if it is integer between 1 and 5. It seems weird to me.

Comment: Try it, may work: ` 'hilightColor' => 'required_if:hilightColorBool|integer|min:1|max:5'`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working - "Validation rule required_if requires at least 2 parameters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on from my comment, i may do it like this:

```
$rules = [
    'hilightColorBool' => 'required|boolean',
];

if (is_bool($request->get('hilightColorBool'))) {
    $rules['hilightColor'] = 'required|integer|min:1|max:5';      
}
```

then simply do:

```
$request->validate($rules);
```

Comment: Yea, I did it basing on your answer, but instead of `if (is_bool($request->get('hilightColorBool')))` it should be `if ($request['hilightKidsWithNonstandardDiet'] == true)`. Thanks.